# How type erasure works here?

Tags: java, generics

Can some one help me to find out how to apply Type erasure/generics to make it work.

```
Set<? extends Object> ss = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<? extends Object> sa = new HashSet<Integer>();
ss.addAll(sa);
```

Now it throwing compilation error, since it will check for type at compile time.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Only store integers or any old object?

Comment: Trying to add HashSet<SubType> to another HashSet<SubType>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do you know why it is not working?

They are two separate wildcards.  Although they looks the same, they are still separate.  Hence, first `? extends Object` (in fact you can simply write it `?`) is simply different from the second.

And, whenever you are using wildcard, don't expect to refer the type.  However you are doing so in `addAll()` which require type checking.

If you are having these logic in a method, you can give proper type parameter to your method:

```
public static <T> void addToFirst(Set<T> first, Set<T> second) {
    first.addAll(second);
}
```

So that type checking can be done to make sure that first and second are of the same type.

Using raw type may be another choice.

Ask yourself if you really need to use wildcard in the type param.  Simply make use of `Set<Integer>` should be most straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can consider your type-erased source will look like

```java
Set ss = new HashSet();
set sa = new HashSet();
ss.addAll(sa); // compilation error
```

**if it's compiled**

```
$ cat Erased.java
import java.util.*;

public class Erased {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Set<Integer> ss = new HashSet<Integer>();
        final Set<Integer> sa = new HashSet<Integer>();

        ss.addAll(sa);
    }
}

$ javap -c Erased
Compiled from "Erased.java"
public class Erased {
  public Erased();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class java/util/HashSet
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/HashSet."<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: new           #2                  // class java/util/HashSet
      11: dup
      12: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/util/HashSet."<init>":()V
      15: astore_2
      16: aload_1
      17: aload_2
      18: invokeinterface #4,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Set.addAll:(Ljava/util/Collection;)Z
      23: pop
      24: return
}
```

Here comes decompiled source code

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Erased
{
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
  {
    HashSet localHashSet1 = new HashSet();
    HashSet localHashSet2 = new HashSet();

    localHashSet1.addAll(localHashSet2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry If my question is not clear. My question is how to apply Type erasure, so that addAll method accept localHashSet2.

Comment: Type Erasure is something that applied by the compiler, not you.